# Can a cordova version upgrade break builds?

Tags: ios, cordova, package.json

### Problem

I've been having a number of platform issues that seem to be related to the version of Cardova that I'm running.

I had a working project, but after doing a fresh install with newest versions of Cordova a few of my plugins are now unresponsive. I'm working to address them individually.

### Question

The above leads me to believe that to assure a valid fresh install, I need to specify the required Cordova versions in my `package.json` file as a dependency.

Is there a best practice for this? Has anyone else run into this issue?

### System

Here is my current system information:

```
OS: Mac OS X Yosemite 
Node Version: v0.12.0 
Cordova CLI: 4.1.2 Ionic
CLI Version: 1.3.19 
Xcode version: Xcode 6.1.1 Build version 6A2008a 
ios-sim version: 3.1.1  
ios-deploy version: 1.5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It's almost always best to specify the version of a package you are expecting, as opposed to a '*' dependency.  This way, as you mention, a fresh install will always start from a known good state.  This is important for other developers starting up, but also for a fresh deployment!

This is anecdotal, but on my team we deployed some changes to production on a fresh install, and without realizing it a package was updated that broke some of our code.  It certainly made for a frantic few hours as we tried to track down the issue.  It took longer to find it because we were first looking at the code we had actually changed before thinking of the updated modules.

My team doesn't use it, so I can't speak too much about it, but check out [Node Shrinkwrap](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/02/27/managing-node-js-dependencies-with-shrinkwrap/), which attempts to solve some of the above problems.

In short, my recommendation is to specify at least a `^` when specifying the version.  This will let you update minor versions, but not update to major versions.  It also means you're trusting the author to not introduce breaking changes in the minor version though!

Hope this helps!